# IS any Editor is available to configure react - redux & git basic setup in Local?

Tags: git

I need to git setup in my local machine. how can i set and which editor is to be support?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I need to use windows7,10 and Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Git for Windows https://git-scm.com/download/win

IDEs with Git integration: JetBrains WebStorm, Visual Studio Code

OR

A standalone GUI: https://tortoisegit.org/download/